# Pulling out the blockquote in wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pull out everything inside `<blockquote>` tags from my **wordpress** posts.

I've tried using

```
<?php  
  $content = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', '', get_the_content());

  echo $content;
?>
```

But was told `preg_replace` isn't a good method, and can't figure out the code to put the `blockquote` back in (in another location)

Comment: Use `preg_match`. http://php.net/preg_match

Comment: I don't know what your ultimate goal is, but perhpas you can use javascript for this. With jQuery you can write `$('blockquote').text()`

Comment: If it's actually critical that this work, don't use regex. What if I decided my block looks like this `<blockquote>foobar<!-- </blockquote> teehee --> and i'm still in a blockquote</blockquote>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'rm_quotes' );
function rm_quotes($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~", "", $content);       
    return $content;
}
```

Applying it in a filter is your best option.

Comment: Ok, it just seems that using preg_replace is not a good idea (not familiar why) as I mentioned a lot of people saying, including those above

Comment: Did anyone happen to comment on why? I'd be curious to know their alternative... `preg_replace` is used to replace a string, while `preg_match` is used to search a string.

Comment: There was just mention that it was far less efficient, but not to many alternatives were given